# pcolor in scatter plot matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, plot

I have a large matrix  `DAT(50000+,42)`. I am plotting 2 rows of this matrix on the x and y axes, and want the plot points to vary in color due to the value of a separate row. Can anybody advise? `pcolor` will not work for me due to "color data input must be a matrix" error.
TIA

```
X = DAT(:,21);

Y = DAT(:,22);

Z = DAT(:,28);

plot(X,Y,'*');

hold on

pcolor(X,Y,Z);

hold off
```

Comment: If you have access to the statistics toolbox then 'gscatter' will colour by groups: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gscatter.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using [scatter()](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html)

```
% random sample data
DAT = randn(30,42);
X = DAT(:,21);
Y = DAT(:,22);
Z = DAT(:,28);

scatter(X,Y,50,Z); % x,y,size,color -> size can also be a vector
% scatter(X,Y,50,Z,'*'); % to also change the marker type
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can select the colors from an array generated with `colormap` like this:

```
DAT = randn(30,42);
X = DAT(:,21);
Y = DAT(:,22);
Z = DAT(:,28);

[dummy ID]=sort(Z);
colors=colormap(jet(length(Z)));

figure
for i=1:length(Z)
plot(X(i),Y(i),'*','Color',colors(ID(i),:));
hold on
end
```

The only issue with this technique is that you cannot do plots with millions of points because of the looped plotting, but otherwise it works like a charm:

[image]